# Throw Error with loop of await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, loops, async-await

I'm struggling with a loop of async await function. I'm creating an API which POST a request to another API. I have to make a loop because users could insert many items at once in the database.

The API that I call rejects Parallel executions so I can't use `Promise.all` :/

In order to implement that service I made a function to insert one object :

```
const addValue = async (ID:number, cookie: string) => {
    try {
        const addValueBody = await addValueQuery(ID:number)
        const header = { 'cookie': cookie, 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        const fetchResult = fetch('http://api-to-call.xyz', { method: `POST`, headers: header, body: addValueBody })
        const response = await fetchResult
        const jsonData = await response.json()
        return jsonData
     } catch (e) {
        throw Error(e.message)
    }
}
```

And a function which will execute `addValue` inside a for loop :

```
const addMulti = async (values: any, cookie: string) => {
    for (const item of values) {
           await addValue(item.ID, cookie)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call addMulti and  if there is an Error I have a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Also I tried to put de `for ... in` or `await addValue` inside a `try catch` but it doesn't catch the Error(s)

Hence, I have 2 questions :

How can I throw en Error if it occurs during the execution of the loop ?
Is it possible to break the loop if there is an error ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: *"The problem is that when I call addMulti and if there is an Error I have a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning."* Please show how you're making that call. That's where the problem is.

Comment: Does `addValue(values.ID, cookie)` relly have to use `values`, not `item`?

Comment: @Cerberus of course yes but I simplified the code for the question, that's why it's not a 100% clean ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I throw en Error if it occurs during the execution of the loop ? Is it possible to break the loop if there is an error ?

Your code does that already, by `await`ing `addValue`. If `addValue` throws an error, since `addMulti` doesn't `catch`, it terminates `addMulti` as well.

> The problem is that when I call addMulti and if there is an Error I have a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

The code you've shown is correct¹, the problem is that it appears you have no error handling on the call to `addMulti`. That code must either:

- Handle errors from it (via `try`/`catch` in an `async` function if you don't want to allow it to propagate, or via the `catch` method if using the promise directly), or
- Propagate the error to something that will handle it (by not catching it in an `async` function, or by returning the promise in a non-`async` function)

So for instance, if the call to `addMulti` is in a non-`async` function and if nothing calling that function will handle errors, you need to handle it at that stage:

```
addMulti(/*...*/)
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report the error
    });
```

If it's in an `async` function but nothing handles that `async` function's errors, then:

```
try {
    await addMulti(/*...*/);
} catch (e) {
     // ...handle/report the error
}
```

---

¹ ...other than it seems odd to catch `e` and then do `throw Error(e.message)`; just let the error propagate.

Comment: TY :) That's works, In fact it's a silly mistake that I made. I just forgot `try addMulti(...) catch ` 
I use `e.message` because I have a Error Handler and if I just throw `e` the handler received x `Error :` because I have functions of functions of functions ...

Answer (score 1):

When you get `UnhandledPromiseRejection` working with async functions, it almost surely means that you didn't catch the thrown error. In your case you could just wrap the whole loop in `try{...} catch{...}` block:

```
const addMulti = async (values: any, cookie: string) => {
    try {
        for (const item of values) {
           await addValue(item.ID, cookie)
       }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error occured in async function')
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppressing the error in `addMulti` is an anti-pattern, the caller should know the operation failed so it can do something with that failure. The problem is in the *caller* of `addMulti`.

Comment: As I said I've already tried to do this but it doesn't work :)

Comment: It's interesting. I just copied this function, used simplified `addValue` (which simply waits a second and then returns on one ID and throws on another), and handler worked just well - error was caught, loop was broken. I won't argue with @T.J.Crowder comment about this being antipattern, it sounds reasonable, but I'm interested in why this could not work...

Comment: @Cerberus - I can probably explain what's going on, if you post a link to a fiddle?